# is there a way to avoid the nested loop in this code?

Tags: javascript, time-complexity

I'm building a chrome extension that lets the user replace words with tiny images. this is the code I have.

```
lookup=[['text','img.png']...];
var text = document.querySelectorAll('h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,p,li,td,caption,span,a')

for (let i=0; i< text.length; i++) {
    var height = window.getComputedStyle(text[i]).fontSize
    for (let j=0;j<lookup.length;j++){
        text[i].innerHTML = text[i].innerHTML.replace(new RegExp(lookup[j][0],"gi"),"<img src=\"img/"+lookup[j][1]+"\" width=\""+height+"\" height=\""+height+"\">");
    }
}
```

since this code has to run every time any text in the page changes I'm afraid the nested loop might cause serious performance degradation. is there anything in javascript that can avoid it?

Comment: Couldn't a part of this be replaced with CSS? CSS would make possible to change only the new text to images, you wouldn't need to recreate the entire page.

Comment: @Teemu I am not very familiar with css

Answer (score 1):

You could create an object lookup and create a regex with alternation `|`. Use a function as the second parameter in `replace`, and use the `lookup` object to get the image based on the match

```
const lookup= { 'text': 'img.png' },
      elements = document.querySelectorAll('h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,p,li,td,caption,span,a'),
      regex = new RegExp(Object.keys(lookup).join("|"), 'gi')

elements.forEach(e => {
  const height = window.getComputedStyle(e).fontSize;
  e.innerHTML = e.innerHTML.replace(regex, m => `<img src="img/${lookup[m]}" width="${height}" />`)
})
```